# Removing entries in excel with the same prefix but different suffix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-2016

I need help with my spreadsheet

the spreadsheet looks something like this:

| Hostname | A header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| host1-dns | text 11 | text 12 |
| host1-ftp | text 11 | text 12 |
| host1-ntp | text 11 | text 12 |
| host1-vip | text 11 | text 12 |
| host2-dns | text 21 | text 22 |
| host2-ftp | text 21 | text 22 |
| host2-ntp | text 21 | text 22 |
| host3-dns | text 31 | text 32 |
| host3-ftp | text 31 | text 32 |
| host4 | text 41 | text 42 |
| host5-sans | text 51 | text 52 |

I need to create a table eliminating duplicate hosts.  In my table:

- host1-dns, host1-ftp, host1-ntp, host1-vip is just one host and should be counted once
- host names (prefixes) does not have uniform number of characters
- suffixes do not have uniform number of characters as well
- prefixes and suffices are separated by a hyphen

In the end, the table should look like this:

| Hostname | A header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| host1 | text 11 | text 12 |
| host2 | text 21 | text 22 |
| host3 | text 31 | text 32 |
| host4 | text 41 | text 42 |
| host5 | text 51 | text 52 |

I am open to any implementation, formula, or macro.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is it the case that the **headers** for each "host-name" will be identical, as you show?  If not, how do you want them displayed?

Comment: Not really.  some hosts have these formats:
* hostname
- hostname-some ID code
- hostname-some ID code-servertype (ntp, ftp,etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Add helper column with formula:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2&"-")-1)
```

then use `Remove duplicates` dialog for last three column:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Uniquify Table

- In this solution it is assumed that your table starts in cell `A1`, has headers and has three columns, and you want to replace it with the result.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub uniquifyTable()
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
                Data(i, 1) = Left(Data(i, 1), _
                    InStr(1, Data(i, 1) & "-", "-") - 1)
            Next i
            .Value = Data
        End With
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily using `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010+)

Paste the `M-Code` into the Advanced Editor

On Line 2, ensure the referenced table name is the same as that of your original data Table.

Note that the Headers should split into a number of columns depending on the number of unique headers per hostname.

Examine the `Applied Steps` window and the embedded comments to understand what is going on.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblHosts"]}[Content],

    //split off the part after the hyphen
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Hostname", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Hostname"}),

    //Group by hostnames
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Hostname"}, 
           {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Hostname=nullable text, A header=nullable text, Another header=nullable text]}}),

    //combine headers into a unique, sorted list
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Header", each 
        List.Sort(
            List.Distinct(
                List.Combine(
                    {Table.Column([Grouped],"A header"),
                     Table.Column([Grouped],"Another header")
                    })
        ))),

    //split the list into a single item per column
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Header", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Header", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv))
    
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1"
```

[image]